# Get data from API using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display information from an external API [here](http://zipitprod.com.leaf.arvixe.com/api/event?$orderby=StartDateUTC,%20Distance&$top=50&day=7&dist=100&lat=40.1273&long=-82.9182) using JSON. I have a file called default.asp. Inside I have my html and a script with this function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://zipitprod.com.leaf.arvixe.com/api/event?$orderby=StartDateUTC,+Distance&$top=50&day=7&dist=100&lat=40.1273&long=-82.9182',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Success: "+response.responseText);                       
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Did not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
                alert("Error: "+msg);
            },
        });
```

For some reason, I get status code 0. Should I not use JSON/AJAX or is there something wrong with my function? I have googled for the status code 0 and I get that it can fail with typos or unreachable DNS. It should be public and I am using the Postman app to help test and it works there.

Comment: Open the browser's Javascript console, look at the error message and look it up on google. Basically you can't call the API from the browser because of the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

Your API calls are failing due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), it's a security measure to stop malicious scripts from doing nasty stuff such as hijacking your sessions on other websites (see: [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)).

You can still get the data from the requested source, however you'll have to do it server-side, and allow the user to request it from your host.

---

Side note: You're requesting [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) from the API call you're making, [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a format that uses curly braces like javascript objects do like so: `{"key":"value"}` *(hence the name JavaScript Object Notation)*

Comment: So I've read you need to add a header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" but I can't find how to do this with my default.asp file. Anytime I try to do that I get "An error occurred on the server when processing the URL".